# How to use Mysql2 transactions with prepared statements

Tags: mysql, ruby, transactions, prepared-statement

How would I build a transaction using prepared statements with MySQL2 in Ruby?

To execute a prepared statement I'd use:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ?"
statement = $client.prepare(query)

result = statement.execute(1)

result.map do |row|
  data.push(row)
end

return data
```

And I'd use this to execute a transaction:

```
class DBConnector
  def transaction(&block)
    raise ArgumentError, "No block was given" unless block_given?
    begin
      client.query("BEGIN")
      yield
      client.query("COMMIT")
    rescue
      client.query("ROLLBACK")
    end
  end
end
```

and:

```
DBConnector.transaction do
  # your db queries here
end
```

How do I combine the two successfully?

Comment: A) Global variables? That's something you really want to avoid. B) If you're writing a wrapper around `mysql2`, why not just use [Sequel](https://sequel.jeremyevans.net) which already does this and way, way more?

Comment: Agreed with the recommendation for [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/). You'd be way ahead learning to use a good ORM instead of trying to talk directly to the interface. Sequel supports [transactions and prepared statements](https://sequel.jeremyevans.net/2010/06/22/prepared-transactions.html).

Comment: ...along with "[Prepared Transactions / Two-Phase Commit](https://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/transactions_rdoc.html#label-Prepared+Transactions+-2F+Two-Phase+Commit)".